# Find Fibonacci prime numbers

Tags: c, for-loop, primes, fibonacci, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3, count, input_num;

    printf("Please enter the number of terms: ");
    scanf("%d", &input_num);
    
    printf("%d\n%d\n", n1, n2);
    
    for (count = 3; count <= input_num; count++) {
        n3 = n1 + n2;
        printf("%d\n", n3);
    
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
    }
}
```

The above code output it just a Fibonacci number, but I want to find Fibonacci prime numbers. How to insert prime number in this code?

The result should be like:

```
Please enter the number of terms: 6
Among the first 6 terms of Fibonacci series that are also prime: 2 3 5
```

Comment: Start by writing a function to tell if a number is prime or not.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Change `int n1 = 0` to `int n1 = 1` and you should get the desired output for an input of 6.

Comment: This, as most questions which give a strong impression of being a homework dump without a plausible own attempt, lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying yourself. To improve have a look at the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and at [ask]. With my short comment above I want to illustrate that your question gives the impression that you did not really spend any thought or effort on it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function, lets call it `isPrime()` that filters out the prime and non-prime numbers.
Here is what the logic of it might be like:

Go through all numbers that are more than 1 (every number is divisible by 1) and are less than or equal to the square root of the input, lets call it `n`, and check if the input is divisible by those numbers, returning false if it is divisible, and returning true otherwise. Since we know that prime numbers are only divisible by 1 and itself, this will work.

Here is what it might look like:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
bool isPrime(int x) {
    int n = /* Square root of x */;
    if (/* x is less than or equal to 2 */) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (/* x is divisible by n */) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can use this function in your original code:

```c
printf("Among the first %d terms of the Fibonacci series that are also prime: ", input_num);
for (count = 3; count <= input_num; count++) {
    n3 = n1 + n2;
    if (isPrime(n3) == true) {
        printf("%d ", n3);
    }
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n3;
}
```

Comment: Please let me know whether you are aware of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions adnd whether you made a conscious decision on answering this question.

Comment: I am aware now, ill try to edit it out to make the answer less obvious  and make pseudo-code then.

Comment: That would mean to practically start an answering process according to the compromise which I am pretty convinced of. I would respect that. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Nice. Ideally you react to reasonable questions by OP while trying to apply this. But I already like your answer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Please enter the number of terms: ");
scanf("%d", &input_num);

printf("%d\n%d\n", n1, n2);

for(count = 3; count <= input_num; count++){
    n3 = n1 + n2;

    for(int i=2; i<n3; i++){
        if(n3%i==0){
            printf("%d\n", n3);
        }
    

   }
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n3;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please let me know whether you are aware of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions adnd whether you made a conscious decision on answering this question.

Comment: @Yunnosch you're right It would be better if I had given the full code instead of just writing in a very short manner.

Comment: If you think that giving the whole working code would solve any of the two issues I pointed out, then you have misunderstood both.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think you're saying that I should write a optimised code with explanation.

Comment: No. I am saying that a) you should explain your code (which neither needs to be complete nor optimised in any way) and b) you should be aware of the widely accepted compromise on how to helpfully and meaningfully answer to questions which mostly want a solution to a homework exercise and do not ask a focused question as per [ask] which is widely considered to be off-topic. Showing full code (optimised or not) does not fix either problem. Your comment seems to show that you ignored my second comment - and what it refers/links to.

Comment: I see that your answer is a homework trap, in providing code which will fail the exercise on even the least bit of testing. That is an interesting decision on whether and how to answer a homework question with code. Or maybe it is just broken code....

Comment: Got it, I'll keep in mind.

Comment: ... and what do you think about my next comment? Do you agree that your code does not even solve the homework assignment and hence will not be an achieved hand in? I assume that "I'll keep that in mind." does not mean "Yes, I am aware of the error in my code."

Answer (score 0):

We, beginners, should help each other.:)

For starters the number 0 is the first Fibonacci number. That is you need to count Fibonacci numbers starting from `0` and check whether they are prime numbers.

And a for loop like that

```
for (count = 3; count <= input_num; count++) {
```

should also start from `0`.

The used variables that define Fibonacci numbers should have an unsigned integer type as for example `unsigned int` though it will be better to declare them as having the type `unsigned long long int`.

To determine whether a number is a prime number it is better to write a separate function.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the task can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_prime( unsigned long long int n )
{
    int prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;

    for (unsigned long long int i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2)
    {
        prime = n % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}

int main( void )
{
    while (1)
    {
        printf( "Please enter the number of Fibonacci items (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;

        if (scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0) break;

        unsigned long long int fibonacci1 = 0;
        unsigned long long int fibonacci2 = 1;

        int present = 0;

        printf( "Among the first %u items of Fibonacci series there are ", n );

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( is_prime( fibonacci1 ) )
            {
                if (present == 0) printf( "also prime " );

                present = 1;
                printf( "%llu ", fibonacci1 );
            }

            fibonacci2 = fibonacci1 + fibonacci2;
            fibonacci1 = fibonacci2 - fibonacci1;
        }

        if (present == 0) printf( "no prime numbers." );
        puts( "\n" );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Please enter the number of Fibonacci items (0 - exit): 20
Among the first 20 items of Fibonacci series there are also prime 2 3 5 13 89 233 1597

Please enter the number of Fibonacci items (0 - exit): 10
Among the first 10 items of Fibonacci series there are also prime 2 3 5 13

Please enter the number of Fibonacci items (0 - exit): 6
Among the first 6 items of Fibonacci series there are also prime 2 3 5    

Please enter the number of Fibonacci items (0 - exit): 3
Among the first 3 items of Fibonacci series there are no prime numbers.

Please enter the number of Fibonacci items (0 - exit): 0
```